# REGEX to extract the longest name in ducuments

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract names from the documents. 
For example:
"james cunningham" is a name
And I want to extract the name from the documents like:

> james cunningham (born 1973 or 1974) is a canadian stand-up comedian and tv host.

Is there any way to extract the longest name? If there is only "jam" or only "cunningham" in the document so just extract one word. But if "jam" and "cunningham" exist together, extract them both. Assume the name will not be separated in the document.

Here is my java code:

```
        String subArray[]=sub.split(" ");
        StringBuilder patternbuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
            if(i==subArray.length-1){
                patternbuilder.append("("+subArray[i]+" )");
            }else{
                patternbuilder.append("("+subArray[i]+" )"+"|");
            }
        }
        String subpattern=patternbuilder.toString();
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(subpattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(para);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            NamedEntity subEntity=new NamedEntity(jCas, matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            subEntity.setValue(matcher.group());
            entities.setSubject(subEntity);
        }
```

"sub" is the input name string and my way can only find one word in the name.

Comment: With names in lowercase, I doubt there is a valid way to extract them all in a safe way. Perhaps, you need a list of first names to check against, and use a kind of a regex to match from a known first name up to `(born `. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
        if(i==subArray.length-1){
            patternbuilder.append("( ?"+subArray[i]+")?");
        }else{
            patternbuilder.append("( ?"+subArray[i]+")?");
      }
   }
```